# How to know whether it is increasing or decreasing when the size of a Window changes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form and I would like to have different logic when its size increases and decreases.

My only idea is to compare the new size with previous size in the function `private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` and implement the logic accordingly if size increased or decreased.

I am creating this thread because I have suspecision that there is a much more easier also more common with the API way to check whether it increased or decreased.

Edit: comments asked for the logic I am trying to implement.

I have picturebox inside my window
 and when windows size increases picturebox adapts however when it decreases it shows scrollbars.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `SizeChanged`?  Sounds simple enough.  You could override `OnSizeChanged` to do something _before_ the event fires if you want.  Is your problem figuring out if X size is larger or smaller than Z size?

Comment: I doubt there is. The sign of the difference should be simple enough though. Note that if the form is resizable in both directions you may have certain cases where the width is increasing and the height decreasing or vice versa.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.sizechangedeventargs?view=netframework-4.8 Check the properties on the event arguments. You can get old size and compare it to new size

Comment: @Zer0 problem is rather how to get the previous and new sizes

Comment: @Sami but we can't convert EventArgs to SizeChangedEventArgs

Comment: I've looked around for a bit hoping there'd be something new, but from my past experiences. You have to, lets say, globally store the last known screen size, which you set on construction. And then upon OnSizeChanged you have to get the new current window size... and then do the stuff you want to do compared to the previously known windows size.

Comment: You may have not noticed it, but you have `OnResizeBegin` and `OnResizeEnd` (better override the methods than subscribe to the events)

Comment: You should probably explain what logic should be applied, based on these values. Maybe there's a simple solution that doesn't involve a whole bunch of calculations to perform each time the size of a Form changes.

Comment: @Jimi I have picturebox inside my window and when windows size increases picturebox adapts however when it decreases it shows scrollbars.

Comment: You need to use the Anchors and Docking features. These property let you handle layout changes automatically. No code needed. You may also want to set the `Form.MinimumSize` to a *sensible* value (calculated at design-time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that question is left hanging so I better explain my solution.
My intuition was not so off the path, What I simply did is I put the `PictureBox` in some `Panel` in my case `SplitContainer.Panel1`.

`PictureBox` was already a class global for my `Main Window` and `PictureBox` properties `Dock` set to `none` and `Anchor` to `Top, Left` also mentioned  `Panel`'s `AutoScroll` should be set to `True`.

Also I rewrote the event `Panel.SizeChanged()` in such a way where I compare `Panel.ClientSize` dimensions with `PictureBox` dimensions if ever `PictureBox` dimensions are smaller just update them with `Panel.ClientSize` dimensions.

```
        private void splitContainer1_Panel1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pictureBox.Height < splitContainer1.Panel1.ClientSize.Height || pictureBox.Width < splitContainer1.Panel1.ClientSize.Width)
            {
                pictureBox.Height = splitContainer1.Panel1.ClientSize.Height;
                pictureBox.Width = splitContainer1.Panel1.ClientSize.Width;
            }
        }
```

[image: demo]